# Sign of Riemannian and application of commutating formula .

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, ricci-flow

$R_{ijkl}$ is curvature ,$\nabla $ is Riemannian connection ,$f$ is a function on Riemannian manifold. $g^{ij}$ is inverse of $g_{ij}$.

If $\nabla_i\nabla_jv_k-\nabla_j\nabla_iv_k=R_{ijkl}g^{lm}v_m$, How to get that 
$\nabla_i\nabla_j\nabla_kf-\nabla_j\nabla_i\nabla_kf=R_{ijkl}\nabla_lf$ ?

In fact , I don't know whether exactly I have asked what I want to know .The question is from [the paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).In the first picture , what is the mean of $\nabla_i v^j$, I think it should be $\nabla_i (v^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})$.And the same is the $\nabla_iv_j$.Besides, how to get the 1.1.3  ?
And the second picture is about my first quesion.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to know how to extend the covariant differentiation to tensor fields. Then the claimed identity is called the Ricci identity.

Comment: @JohnMa  I think I know how to extend the covariant differentiation to tensor fields. But ,maybe ,there are some difference on the sign.In my opinion ,if $v=v^j\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}$, the $v^j$ just be a function on  manifold ,then $\nabla _i v^j=\frac{\partial v^j}{\partial x^i}$

Comment: @JohnMa But ,In the paper, the $v^j$ seems to mean a vector.

Comment: So do you understand what is $\nabla_i v^j$ and why $\nabla_i v^j = \partial_i v^j + \Gamma_{ik}^j v^k?$ (Yes, $v^j$ is a vector and $v_j$ is a one form)

Comment: in particular, what you write down how to take covariant diff on one form?

Comment: @JohnMa if the $v^j$ is a vector ,then I write it as $v^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$.Then ,$\nabla_iv^j=\nabla_i(v^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})=\frac{\partial v^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}+v^j\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$

Comment: @JohnMa About the 1-form,according to $\nabla_X\omega(Y)=X(\omega(Y))-\omega(\nabla_XY)$,then $v_j=v_jdx^j$,so,$\nabla_iv_j(\partial_k)=\nabla_i(v_jdx^j)(\partial_k)=
\partial_i(v_j<dx^j,\partial_k>)-v_j<dx^j,\Gamma_{ik}^h\partial_h>=
\partial_iv_k-v_j\Gamma_{ik}^j$,so I have $\nabla_i(v_jdx^j)=
(\partial_iv_k-v_j\Gamma_{ik}^j)dx^k$

Comment: Yes, so it seems you solved your first question. For the second one (commuting $\nabla$), it's really just a direct computations.

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks very much,I computed it tomorrow ,It seems to be very complex, I will try it again.Besides,do you know how to compute the red line and 1.1.14 of second picture?

Comment: It's basically the substitution of $v_k = \nabla _k f$ into $(1.1.3)$. You may say that a $g^{ij}$ is missing, but it is common (very very common)  that they assume they are using normal coordinate at a point (which we know always exist at a point) to represent the calculation, so $g_{ij} = g^{ij} = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Yes ,thanks very much.But I'm sorry ,I still don't know how to compute 1.1.14 and the next line of 1.1.14. Could give me some hints? Help me !!

Comment: Actually I cannot see the next line of 1.1.14

Comment: @JohnMa Sorry, I have add it .

Comment: I have computed the 1.1.14, I found I'm so stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 
$$\nabla_i\nabla_j v_k - \nabla_j\nabla_i v_k = R_{ijkl}g^{lm} v_m,$$ 
and put $v_k = \nabla_k f$ gives 
$$\nabla_i\nabla_j \nabla_k f - \nabla_j\nabla_i \nabla_k f= R_{ijkl}g^{lm} \nabla_m f = R_{ijkl} \nabla_l f.$$ 
($g^{lm} = \delta_{lm}$ used). Now put 
$$R_{ij} + \nabla_i\nabla_jf = 0\Rightarrow  \nabla_i\nabla_jf = -R_{ij}$$
into the previous equation gives 
$$\nabla_i(-R_{jk}) - \nabla_j(-R_{ik}) = R_{ijkl} \nabla_l f.$$ 
And that is the same as the second last equation from your linked page. Now take trace on $(j,k)$ gives (as $R_{ii} = R$, $R_{il} = R_{ijjl}$)
$$-\nabla_iR + \nabla_jR_{ij} = R_{ij} \nabla_j f.$$
Then using the Bianchi identity you'll get 
$$(*)\ \ \ \ \ \nabla_i R - 2R_{ij} \nabla_j f = 0.$$
Now 
$$\begin{split} \nabla_i |\nabla f|^2 &=  \nabla_i \left( \nabla_j f\right)^2 \\
&= 2 \nabla_j f \nabla_j \nabla_i f \\
&=-2 \nabla_j f (R_{ij})
\end{split}$$
(Using the definition of gradient Ricci soliton)

As a result, 
$$\begin{split} \nabla_i (|\nabla f|^2 + R) &= \nabla_i |\nabla f|^2 + \nabla_i R \\
&= -2 R_{ij} \nabla_j f + \nabla_i R \\
&=0 
\end{split}$$
by $(*)$. Thus the function $|\nabla f|^2 + R$ is a constant function, hence (1.1.15).

Comment: You are my saviour. Thanks very much. If you go to ChangSha,China, let me treat you to dinner.

Comment: In the first $(*)$,  what's the form of Bianchi identity? $\nabla R(X,Y,Z,W,T)+\nabla R(X,Y,W,T,Z)+\nabla R(X,Y,T,Z,W)=0$ ? But it's seem to do nothing for getting the first $(*)$.

Comment: Take $(j,k)$ trace of the Bianchi identity $\nabla_m R_{ijkl} + \nabla_kR_{ijlm}+ \nabla_lR_{ijmk}=0$ givens $\nabla_m R_{il} + \nabla_j R_{ijlm} + \nabla_l R_{ijmj} = 0$, then $\nabla_m R_{il} + \nabla_j R_{ijlm} - \nabla_l R_{im} =0$. Take again the $(i, l)$ trace gives $\nabla_m R - \nabla_j R_{jm} - \nabla_i R_{im} = 0\Rightarrow \nabla_m R = 2 \nabla _i R_{im}$. @lanse2pty

Comment: Thanks very much. And thanks for your answer of another question .

Comment: because the $R_{im}=R_{mi}$, then $\nabla_i R_{im}=\nabla_i R_{mi}$,then the $(*)$ should be $\nabla_i R + 2R_{ij} \nabla_j f = 0$?

Comment: @lanse2pty Yes you are right.